# How is pgsql connecting with a user name that's not in pgpass.conf, and without ever specifying a password?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am able to connect to the database using psql, without specifying a password, using an account that is NOT in the pgpass.conf file. I wanted to be prompted for a password.  How is this possible?

```
psql -U mike -d employees
```

I have confirmed that psql connected using the 'mike' account:

```
employees=> \conninfo
You are connected to database "employees" as user "mike" on host "localhost" at port "5432".
```

I have confirmed that the account has a password.

```
select * from pg_shadow;

postgres=# select * from pg_shadow;
     usename      | usesysid | usecreatedb | usesuper | userepl | usebypassrls |               passwd                | valuntil | useconfig
------------------+----------+-------------+----------+---------+--------------+-------------------------------------+----------+-----------
mike|    59736 | f           | f        | f       | f            | md5c223b8b4c619d6c9ffb4cf3522284be6 |          |
```

I have confirmed that there's only one pgpass.conf file on my file system.

Setup:

- Windows 10.
- PostgreSQL 10.4 on x86_64-pc-mingw64, compiled by    gcc.exe (Rev5,
  Built by MSYS2 project) 4.9.2, 64-bit

Comment: Show your `pg_hba.conf` file. Very likely your answer is in there.

Comment: The settings in pg_hba.conf were all set to 'trust'. Changing them.

Answer (score 3):

Courtesy of Laurenz Albe in the comment section above.

The issue was because of the settings in pg_hba.conf.  Basically what needs to change is

- trust -> scram-sha-256

Here's how I fixed it. This was tricky. Changing the settings in pg_hba.conf was the easy part. The hard part is re-encrypting the existing passwords in the database to match the new setting so that they can still be used to login afterwards.

1. Leave the settings in pg_hba.conf.
2. Connected to the database using
   "psql -U postgres" issued these commands:

   - set password_encryption to 'scram-sha-256';
   - ALTER USER postgres with password 'currentPassword';
   - ALTER ROLE mike WITH LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'mikesCurrentPassword';
3. Modify the pg_hba.conf file changing 'trust'
   to 'scram-sha-256'.

A further note: A server reset was not required to enable the changes made to pg_hba.conf.

Comment: It is more secure to use `psql`'s `\password` command than `ALTER USER` because a) no clear text password is sent to the server and b) the password cannot be logged.